# Jquery failing to call async and await for indexed db creation

Tags: jquery, indexeddb

I have written the following code to create an indexed db which is working fine but I am making the function asynchronous as follows

```
async function createDb() {
  var request = indexedDB.open("myDB", "1")
   request.onsuccess = function (e) {
   return request.result; // Tried await return request.result
  }
}
```

In my view under document.ready I am calling as follows

```
async function CreateDataBase() {
    const result = await createDb();
    console.log(result);
 }
```

But some how it is always returning null, I thought like the call is ending even before async and await. How to call async and await correctly. Also before creating the database I would like to check if db exists and then create

I wrote up as follows which I would like to call before creating database and create it db doesn't exists.

```
function dbExists() {
var dbExists = true;
var request = indexedDB.open("myDB");
request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    e.target.transaction.abort();
    dbExists = false;
}
return dbExists;
}
```

Comment: This is not how async/await works. You will need to learn more about async/await. In particular, you will want to wait to resolve the open promise. You cannot just return the value from a deferred callback.

Comment: Can I get any sample code I tired out as per the suggestions but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code for you:

```js
function open(name, version) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = indexedDB.open(name, version);
    request.onsuccess = (event) => resolve(event.target.result);
    request.onerror = (event) => reject(event.target.error);
  });
}

open('myDatabase', 1).then(db => {
  console.log('opened database');
  // do stuff here with db
}).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hi Josh in IE-11 I am getting an error at this line ` return new Promise`